# Progress issue in BG Worker

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

When the following code executes, the progress bar doesn't go upto the end and when its 90% complete, the message box is shown. I find the problem with the for loop but don't know what the real problem inside is. Please help. I searched the same kind of questions here in stackoverflow too. But didn't find any solution.

**Here is my code:**

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{          
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        Thread.Sleep(100);               
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;                
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check if the Maximum  property of the progressbar is 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your problem. The problem lies in the DoWork method that is too fast and the progress bar repaint of the bar cannot keep up. If you try to change that Thread.Sleep to a bigger interval (I have tried 300ms) you could be see the full painting.

However, you could help the progress bar in its repainting if you move the MessageBox.Show("Done") before the setting to zero of the progressbar.Value

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
        progressBar1.Value = 0;                
    }
}
```

Comment: Any solution for rectifying that pal?

Comment: Moving the `MessageBox.Show("Done")` before the setting the `progressbar.Value = 0;` could help a lot.. :-)

Comment: Ya tried that too but with the same result. The problem might be with the progress bar re-paint as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Change `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);`

To:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i+1);
```

**Or** change the loop to:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
```

Comment: You are right pal. The last iteration is not taken into account. So changing the loop values as you said is right. But eventhough we change it, the progress bar is somewhat slower than we expect it to be as @Steve (above) said.